# How to create Heterogenous Layouts from json response

Tags: android, json, android-layout, layout-inflater, heterogeneous

Hi please help me inflate layout based on json response type
I am trying to merge http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/ this tutorial with this https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

But i'm facing some issues

my **json response** form

```
[
   { "type":"sports",
      "image":"http://example.com/image.jpg",
      "name":"Super Commando Dhruva"
   },
   {
"type":"health",
      "image":"http://example.com/image.jp",
      "name":"Parmanu"
   }
]
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.androidcss.jsonexample;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private RecyclerView mRVFishPrice;
    private AdapterFish mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Make call to AsyncTask
        new AsyncLogin().execute();
    }

    private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                url = new URL("http://example.com/response.json");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            List<DataFeed> data=new ArrayList<>();

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataFeed fishData = new DataFeed();
                    fishData.fishImage= json_data.getString("image");
                    fishData.fishName= json_data.getString("type");
                    fishData.catName= json_data.getString("name");
                   // fishData.sizeName= json_data.getString("size_name");
                    //fishData.price= json_data.getInt("price");
                    data.add(fishData);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
                mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data);
                mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

My **adapter**

```
package com.androidcss.jsonexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class AdapterFish extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataFeed> data= Collections.emptyList();
    DataFeed current;
    int currentPos=0;
    private final int USER = 0, IMAGE = 1;
    // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public AdapterFish(Context context, List<DataFeed> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }


    // return total item from List
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        DataFeed current=data.get(position);
        if (data.get(position) instanceof DataFeed) {
            return USER;
        } else if (data.get(position) instanceof String) {
            return IMAGE;
        }
        return -1;
    }






    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

        switch (viewType) {
            case USER:
                View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder1, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder1(v1);
                break;
            case IMAGE:
                View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder2, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder2(v2);
                break;
            default:
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fish, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new MyHolder(v);
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
            case USER:
                ViewHolder1 vh1 = (ViewHolder1) viewHolder;
                configureViewHolder1(vh1, position);
                break;
            case IMAGE:
                ViewHolder2 vh2 = (ViewHolder2) viewHolder;
                configureViewHolder2 (vh2, position, int);
                break;
            //default:
              //  RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder vh = (RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder) viewHolder;
               // configureDefaultViewHolder(vh, position);
               // break;
        }
    }

    //private void configureDefaultViewHolder(RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder vh, int position) {
      //  vh.getLabel().setText((CharSequence) items.get(position));
    //}

    private void configureViewHolder1(ViewHolder1 vh1, int position) {
        DataFeed current =  data.get(position);
        if (current != null) {
            vh1.getLabel1().setText("Name: " + current.fishName);
            //vh1.getLabel2().setText("Hometown: " + current.hometown);
        }
    }

    private void configureViewHolder2(ViewHolder2 vh2) {
        vh2.getImageView().setImageResource(R.drawable.robbie);
    }




    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textFishName;
        ImageView ivFish;
        TextView textSize;
        TextView textType;
        TextView textPrice;

        // create constructor to get widget reference
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textFishName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textFishName);
            ivFish= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.banner);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String type="sports";
String type1="health";

JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


type = json_data.getString("type");

if (Objects.equals(type,type)){
    fishData.fishImage= json_data.getString("image");
}

else if (Objects.equals(type,type1)){
    fishData.fishImage= json_data.getString("image");
}
```